# HTTP2 request grammar

Tags: http, grammar, http2

Wondering if there exists a language grammar for an HTTP2 request/response. For example, a I found [this](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) which is a grammar for HTTP 1.1 dated from 1999. Not sure if there is an equivalent for HTTP2.

Comment: [**This document**](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231) is from 2014 and directly obsoletes the one you referenced, though is still only for HTTP/1.1 unfortunately. I'm not sure one exists for HTTP2.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540 - I am not sure why people aren't sure whether one exists for HTTP2. It is instantly searchable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540

RFC's are pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

There is a spec - RFC 7540 - but not a "language grammar" (which sounds like you're looking for something like an ABNF).